# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Here is my function to add a row in db:

```
    public static void insertNote(string title, string text, int languageId)
    {
        var dbo = new UsersContext();
        Models.NoteForm note = new NoteForm
        {
            Text = text,
            Title = title,
            languageId = languageId,
            userId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
        };
        dbo.Note.Add(note);
        dbo.SaveChanges();

    }
```

And the model used:

```
public class NoteForm
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Language")]  
    public int languageId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("id")]
    public virtual Language language { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int userId { get; set; }

}
```

At this line :

```
dbo.SaveChanges();
```

i get this error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when 
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to NULL

With the debugger i see that the language property

```
 public virtual Language language { get; set; }
```

is set to null. that's probably the reason why i get this error.
How could i solve this problem ? I can't initialize this property, i just use it to navigate through a table.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you set the language property?

Comment: Hum, because i have nothing to save in it actually .. i just want to save a new Note object, not a Language

Comment: You set `id` as language  foreign key. It should be `languageId` `[ForeignKey("languageId")]`

Comment: @FieryA But if the language is a foreign key with another table then it needs to be set. Thats why you have it as a foreign key.

Comment: The name of my primary key in the language table is "Id" and not languageId (which is however the name of the foreign key in the noteForm table )

Comment: @FieryA ForeignKey attribute looks for the property name in the current class not in type of navigation class. so it should be `[ForeignKey("languageId")]`

Comment: You are right, it solved my problem completely. thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's trying to insert the Id in the database instead of using the auto-generated that you have in the database. It doesn't have to do with the language.

Set it to databasegenerated so it won't try to insert it

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```